# how to make ion-datetime's display the picker in a modal or bottom page slider instead of directly display it

Tags: ionic-framework, datetimepicker

I'm doing an ionic project using Ionic 6 and I need a datetime field in my form.

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Available From</ion-label>
          <ion-datetime min="1994-03-14" max="2012-12-09" value="2008-09-02"></ion-datetime>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

From what I have searched in many sources, it seems like the correct behavior should be button which is when it is clicked will display a slider up from the bottom of the page. The selector displays scrollable columns that can be used to individually specify values for years, months, days, hours, and minutes.

Instead of that, what I get is the picker is displayed instead of button or anything.

[image]

Am I missing something? I tried all usage example in the documentation and all of them are displayed like that. Please help.

Comment: It seems like ionic v6 completely changed the layout of the datetime picker (https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime) and the picker-columns are gone and the component now shows the component you see. With v5 you should get the columns in a bottom sheet that you expected to see.

I don't really know why ionic decided to go with this because IMO this feels a lot worse than the previous implementation.

Answer (score 5):

It's still possible by using ion-popover.

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label position="stacked">Date of birth</ion-label>
    <ion-input value="{{ user.birthDate | date: 'dd MMM yyyy' }}" id="date"></ion-input>
    <ion-popover trigger="date" >
        <ng-template>
            <ion-datetime presentation="date" [(ngModel)]="user.birthDate" locale="en-US"></ion-datetime>
        </ng-template>
    </ion-popover>
</ion-item>
```

[image: Example]

All credit to Damir Arh who posted the solution here: https://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20220107-DatePickerPopupInIonic6.html

Answer (score 2):

Since **v6** you can (and should) use `datetime-button` with either `ion-modal` or `ion-popover`:

```
<ion-datetime-button datetime="datetime"></ion-datetime-button>
<ion-modal [keepContentsMounted]="true">
  <ng-template>
    <ion-datetime id="datetime"></ion-datetime>
  </ng-template>
</ion-modal>
```

Upd: And if you need [wheel-style pickers](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime-button) use `prefer-wheel` attribute.

Source: [Ionic UI Components → Datetime Button](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime-button)

Answer (score 1):

The `ion-datetime` has changed in Ionic v6.
To have a text field displaying the date in your form and have the calendar picker in a popup, use it like in the following example (`startdate` is the date variable):

```
<ion-row>
   <ion-col>Date:</ion-col>
   <ion-col id="open-date-input" class="ion-text-end" style="margin-right: 10px;">
     <ion-text>{{ startdate|date:'shortDate':undefined:this.translate.currentLang }}</ion-text>
   </ion-col>
   <ion-popover trigger="open-date-input" show-backdrop="false">
     <ng-template>
       <ion-datetime
          #popoverDate
          value="{{startdate}}"
          presentation="date"
          showDefaultButtons=true
          (ionChange)="startdate = popoverDate.value"
        ></ion-datetime>
     </ng-template>
   </ion-popover>          
</ion-row>
```

Of course you may omit/replace the date formatting pipe in the `ion-text` to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using ionic with react and styled components and below I extracted from my code base the solution using an IonModal.

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import {IonDatetime, IonIcon, IonModal} from "@ionic/react";
import {caretDown, caretDownOutline} from "ionicons/icons";

const IonModalBox = styled(IonModal)`
      --height: '45%';
      &::part(content){
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
      }
`

const DateTimePickerContainer = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-content: center;
    width: 100%;
`

const ValueContainer = styled.div`
    flex-grow: 1;
`

interface DateTimePickerComponentProps {
    value: string | null;
}

export const DateTimePickerComponent: React.FC<DateTimePickerComponentProps> = (props) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState<string | null>(props.value);
    const [showDialog, setShowDialog] = useState(false);

    const onClickHandler = () => {
        setShowDialog(true);
    }
    const onIonChangeHandler = (value: string | null) => {
        setValue(value);
        setShowDialog(false);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <DateTimePickerContainer onClick={onClickHandler}>
                <ValueContainer>{value}</ValueContainer>
                <IonIcon md={caretDown} ios={caretDownOutline}/>
            </DateTimePickerContainer>
            <IonModalBox isOpen={showDialog} onDidDismiss={() => setShowDialog(false)}>
                <IonDatetime value={value}
                             onIonChange={e => onIonChangeHandler(e.detail.value || null)}
                             size={"cover"}
                             showDefaultButtons={true}/>
            </IonModalBox>
        </>

    )
}
```